# PHP multidimensional array sorting in an other array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimentional array in PHP

i want to sort it like that :

```
Array (
[4570] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1647
        [date] => 2017-13
    )

[4571] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1647
        [date] => 2017-14
    )

[4573] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1705
        [date] => 2017-15
    )

[4574] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1705
        [date] => 2017-15
    )
 )
```

i want to make an array like this :

```
Array
(
  [2017-13] => Array
  (
     all the ids associated with 2017-13
  )

  [2017-14] => Array
  (
     all the ids associated with 2017-14
     [id]
     [id]
     ...
  )
)
```

etc

could be really nice if someone helps me
didn't find sample of codes to it 
thank you

Comment: Please try at least something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$input = [
    4570 => [
        'id' => 1647,
        'date' => '2017-13'
    ],
    4571 => [
        'id' => 1647,
        'date' => '2017-14'
    ],
    4573 => [
        'id' => 1705,
        'date' => '2017-15'
    ],
    4574 => [
        'id' => 1705,
        'date' => '2017-15'
    ]
];
$output = [];

array_walk($input, function($entry) use (&$output) {
    $output[$entry['date']][] = $entry['id'];
});

print_r($output);
```

The output of above code obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [2017-13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1647
        )

    [2017-14] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1647
        )

    [2017-15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1705
            [1] => 1705
        )

)
```

---

If you want to prevent `id`s getting added *twice* (as in the example for key `2017-15`), you simply add a condition:

```
array_walk($input, function($entry) use (&$output) {
    if (   ! isset($output[$entry['date']]) 
        || ! in_array($entry['id'], $output[$entry['date']])) {
        $output[$entry['date']][] = $entry['id'];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats not an sort. I would solve this by creating a new array by iterating over your current one.

```
$t = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (!isset($t[$item['date']]) {
        $t[$item['date']] = [];
    }
    $t[$item['date']][] = $item['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<?php

$sourceArray = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1647,
        'date' => '2017-13'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 1647,
        'date' => '2017-13'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 1647,
        'date' => '2017-14'
    )
);

$resultArray = array();

foreach ($sourceArray as $k=>$v) {
    $resultArray[$v['date']][] = $v['id'];
}

?>
```